# Getting a simple Neural Network to work from scratch in C++

Tags: c++, neural-network

I have been trying to get a simple double XOR neural network to work and I am having problems getting backpropagation to train a really simple feed forward neural network.
I have been mostly been trying to follow [this](http://galaxy.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html) guide in getting a neural network but have at best made programs that learn at extremely slow rate.

As I understand neural networks:

1. Values are computed by taking the result of a sigmoid function from the sum of all inputs to that neuron.  This is then fed to the next layer using the weight for each neuron
2. At the end of running the error is computed for the output neurons, then using the weights, error is back propagated back by simply multiplying the values and then summing at each Neuron
3. When all of the errors are computed the weights are adjusted by the delta = weight of connection * derivative of the sigmoid (value of Neuron weight is going to) * value of Neuron that connection is to * error of neuron * amount of output error of neuron going to * beta (some constant for learning rate)

[This](http://github.com/matthewfl/neural-net-attempts) is my current muck of code that I am trying to get working.  I have a lot of other attempts somewhat mixed in, but the main backpropagation function that I am trying to get working is on line 293 in Net.cpp

Comment: @Martin nothing wrong with C++ for this.

Comment: C/C++ Perceptron: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccperceptron/

Answer (score 25):

Have a look at [15 Steps to implement a Neural Network](http://code-spot.co.za/2009/10/08/15-steps-to-implemented-a-neural-net/), it should get you started.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Your link is dead.

Comment: Here's the link from the archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20170813072242/http://code-spot.co.za/2009/10/08/15-steps-to-implemented-a-neural-net/

Answer (score 22):

I wrote a simple a "Tutorial" that you can check out below.

It is a simple implementation of the perceptron model. You can imagine a perceptron as a neural network with only one neuron. There is of curse code that you can test out that I wrote in C++. I go through the code step by step so you shouldn't have any issues.

Although the perceptron isn't really a "Neural Network" it is really helpful if you want to get started and might help you better understand how a full Neural Network works.

Hope that helps!
Cheers! ^_^

---

---

In this example I will go through the implementation of the perceptron model in C++ so that you can get a better idea of how it works.

First things first it is a good practice to write down a simple algorithm of what we want to do.

Algorithm:

1. Make a the vector for the weights and initialize it to 0 (Don't forget to add the bias term)
2. Keep adjusting the weights until we get 0 errors or a low error count.
3. Make predictions on unseen data.

Having written a super simple algorithm let's now write some of the functions that we will need.

- We will need a function to calculate the net's input (e.i ***x * wT*** multiplying the inputs time the weights)
- A step function so that we get a prediction of either 1 or -1
- And a function that finds the ideal values for the weights.

So without further ado let's get right into it.

Let's start simple by creating a perceptron class:

```
class perceptron
{
public:

private:

};
```

Now let's add the functions that we will need.

```
class perceptron
{
public:
    perceptron(float eta,int epochs);
    float netInput(vector<float> X);
    int predict(vector<float> X);
    void fit(vector< vector<float> > X, vector<float> y);
private:

};
```

Notice how the function ***fit*** takes as an argument a vector of vector< float >. That is because our training dataset is a matrix of inputs. Essentially we can imagine that matrix as a couple of vectors ***x*** stacked the one on top of another and each column of that Matrix being a feature.

Finally let's add the values that our class needs to have. Such as the vector ***w*** to hold the weights, the number of ***epochs*** which indicates the number of passes that we will do over the training dataset. And the constant ***eta*** which is the learning rate of which we will multiply each weight update in order to make the training procedure faster by dialing this value up or if ***eta*** is too high we can dial it down to get the ideal result( for most applications of the perceptron I would suggest an ***eta*** value of 0.1 ).

```
class perceptron
{
public:
    perceptron(float eta,int epochs);
    float netInput(vector<float> X);
    int predict(vector<float> X);
    void fit(vector< vector<float> > X, vector<float> y);
private:
    float m_eta;
    int m_epochs;
    vector < float > m_w;
};
```

Now with our class set. It's time to write each one of the functions.

We will start from the constructor  ( **perceptron(float eta,int epochs);** )

```
perceptron::perceptron(float eta, int epochs)
{
    m_epochs = epochs; // We set the private variable m_epochs to the user selected value
    m_eta = eta; // We do the same thing for eta
}
```

As you can see what we will be doing is very simple stuff. So let's move on to another simple function. The predict function( ***int predict(vector X);*** ). Remember that what the all ***predict*** function does is taking the net input and returning a value of 1 if the ***netInput*** is bigger than 0 and -1 otherwhise.

```
int perceptron::predict(vector<float> X)
{
    return netInput(X) > 0 ? 1 : -1; //Step Function
}
```

Notice that we used an inline if statement to make our lives easier. Here's how the inline if statement works:

***condition ? if_true : else***

So far so good. Let's move on to implementing the ***netInput*** function( ***float netInput(vector X);*** )

The netInput does the following; ***multiplies the input vector by the transpose of the weights vector***

***x * wT***

In other words, it multiplies each element of the input vector ***x*** by the corresponding element of the vector of weights ***w*** and then takes their sum and adds the bias.

***(x1 * w1 + x2 * w2 + ... + xn * wn) + bias***

***bias = 1 * w0***

```
float perceptron::netInput(vector<float> X)
{
    // Sum(Vector of weights * Input vector) + bias
    float probabilities = m_w[0]; // In this example I am adding the perceptron first
    for (int i = 0; i < X.size(); i++)
    {
        probabilities += X[i] * m_w[i + 1]; // Notice that for the weights I am counting
        // from the 2nd element since w0 is the bias and I already added it first.
    }
    return probabilities;
}
```

Alright so we are now pretty much done last thing we need to do is to write the ***fit*** function which modifies the weights.

```
void perceptron::fit(vector< vector<float> > X, vector<float> y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < X[0].size() + 1; i++) // X[0].size() + 1 -> I am using +1 to add the bias term
    {
        m_w.push_back(0); // Setting each weight to 0 and making the size of the vector
        // The same as the number of features (X[0].size()) + 1 for the bias term
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m_epochs; i++) // Iterating through each epoch
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < X.size(); j++) // Iterating though each vector in our training Matrix
        {
            float update = m_eta * (y[j] - predict(X[j])); //we calculate the change for the weights
            for (int w = 1; w < m_w.size(); w++){ m_w[w] += update * X[j][w - 1]; } // we update each weight by the update * the training sample
            m_w[0] = update; // We update the Bias term and setting it equal to the update
        }
    }
}
```

So that was essentially it. With only 3 functions we now have a working perceptron class that we can use to make predictions!

In case you want to copy-paste the code and try it out. Here is the entire class (I added some extra functionality such as printing the weights vector and the errors in each epoch as well as added the option to import/export weights.)

Here is the code:

The class header:

```
class perceptron
{
public:
    perceptron(float eta,int epochs);
    float netInput(vector<float> X);
    int predict(vector<float> X);
    void fit(vector< vector<float> > X, vector<float> y);
    void printErrors();
    void exportWeights(string filename);
    void importWeights(string filename);
    void printWeights();
private:
    float m_eta;
    int m_epochs;
    vector < float > m_w;
    vector < float > m_errors;
};
```

The class .cpp file with the functions:

```
perceptron::perceptron(float eta, int epochs)
{
    m_epochs = epochs;
    m_eta = eta;
}

void perceptron::fit(vector< vector<float> > X, vector<float> y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < X[0].size() + 1; i++) // X[0].size() + 1 -> I am using +1 to add the bias term
    {
        m_w.push_back(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m_epochs; i++)
    {
        int errors = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < X.size(); j++)
        {
            float update = m_eta * (y[j] - predict(X[j]));
            for (int w = 1; w < m_w.size(); w++){ m_w[w] += update * X[j][w - 1]; }
            m_w[0] = update;
            errors += update != 0 ? 1 : 0;
        }
        m_errors.push_back(errors);
    }
}

float perceptron::netInput(vector<float> X)
{
    // Sum(Vector of weights * Input vector) + bias
    float probabilities = m_w[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < X.size(); i++)
    {
        probabilities += X[i] * m_w[i + 1];
    }
    return probabilities;
}

int perceptron::predict(vector<float> X)
{
    return netInput(X) > 0 ? 1 : -1; //Step Function
}

void perceptron::printErrors()
{
    printVector(m_errors);
}

void perceptron::exportWeights(string filename)
{
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open(filename);

    for (int i = 0; i < m_w.size(); i++)
    {
        outFile << m_w[i] << endl;
    }

    outFile.close();
}

void perceptron::importWeights(string filename)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(filename);

    for (int i = 0; i < m_w.size(); i++)
    {
        inFile >> m_w[i];
    }
}

void perceptron::printWeights()
{
    cout << "weights: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < m_w.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << m_w[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Also if you want to try out an example here is an example I made:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h> 

#include "MachineLearning.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace MachineLearning;

vector< vector<float> > getIrisX();
vector<float> getIrisy();

int main()
{
    vector< vector<float> > X = getIrisX();
    vector<float> y = getIrisy();
    vector<float> test1;
    test1.push_back(5.0);
    test1.push_back(3.3);
    test1.push_back(1.4);
    test1.push_back(0.2);

    vector<float> test2;
    test2.push_back(6.0);
    test2.push_back(2.2);
    test2.push_back(5.0);
    test2.push_back(1.5);
    //printVector(X);
    //for (int i = 0; i < y.size(); i++){ cout << y[i] << " "; }cout << endl;

    perceptron clf(0.1, 14);
    clf.fit(X, y);
    clf.printErrors();
    cout << "Now Predicting: 5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2(CorrectClass=-1,Iris-setosa) -> " << clf.predict(test1) << endl;
    cout << "Now Predicting: 6.0,2.2,5.0,1.5(CorrectClass=1,Iris-virginica) -> " << clf.predict(test2) << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

vector<float> getIrisy()
{
    vector<float> y;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("y.data");
    string sampleClass;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        inFile >> sampleClass;
        if (sampleClass == "Iris-setosa")
        {
            y.push_back(-1);
        }
        else
        {
            y.push_back(1);
        }
    }

    return y;
}

vector< vector<float> > getIrisX()
{
    ifstream af;
    ifstream bf;
    ifstream cf;
    ifstream df;
    af.open("a.data");
    bf.open("b.data");
    cf.open("c.data");
    df.open("d.data");

    vector< vector<float> > X;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        char scrap;
        int scrapN;
        af >> scrapN;
        bf >> scrapN;
        cf >> scrapN;
        df >> scrapN;

        af >> scrap;
        bf >> scrap;
        cf >> scrap;
        df >> scrap;
        float a, b, c, d;
        af >> a;
        bf >> b;
        cf >> c;
        df >> d;
        X.push_back(vector < float > {a, b, c, d});
    }

    af.close();
    bf.close();
    cf.close();
    df.close();

    return X;
}
```

The way I imported the iris dataset isn't really ideal but I just wanted something that worked.

The data files can be found [here.](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_r3mf9HbUrLMXRhWGlTWHA3N1E&usp=sharing)

I hope that you found this helpful!

Note: The code above is there only as an example. As noted by juzzlin it is important that you use `const vector<float> &X` and in general pass the `vector`/`vector<vector>` objects by reference because the data can be very large and passing it by value will make a copy of it (which is inefficient).

Comment: This answer is based largely on a piece of Documentation. Please copy the relevant parts into your answer.

Comment: Please use e.g. `const vector<float> & X` instead of just `vector<float> X`. Now the values are always being copied on every function call.

Comment: @juzzlin That is correct. Thanks for the heads up. I added a note at the end.

Comment: getting printvector is not declared in this scope

Answer (score 8):

Sounds to me like you are struggling with backprop and what you describe above doesn't quite match how I understand it to work, and your description is a bit ambiguous.

You calculate the output error term to backpropagate as the diffrence between the prediction and the actual value multiplied by the derivative of the transfer function.  It is that error value which you then propagate backwards.  The derivative of a sigmoid is calculated quite simply as y(1-y) where y is your output value.  There are lots of proofs of that available on the web.

For a node on the inner layer, you multiply that output error by the weight between the two nodes, and sum all those products as the total error from the outer layer being propagated to the node in the inner layer.  The error associated with the inner node is then multiplied by the derivative of the transfer function applied to the original output value.  Here's some pseudocode:

```
total_error = sum(output_errors * weights)
node_error = sigmoid_derivative(node_output) * total_error
```

This error is then propagated backwards in the same manner right back through the input layer weights.

The weights are adjusted using these error terms and the output values of the nodes

```
weight_change = outer_error * inner_output_value
```

the learning rate is important because the weight change is calculated for every pattern/row/observation in the input data.  You want to moderate the weight change for each row so the weights don't get unduly changed by any single row and so that all rows have an effect on the weights.  The learning rate gives you that and you adjust the weight change by multiplying by it

```
weight_change = outer_error * inner_output_value * learning_rate
```

It is also normal to remember these changes between epochs (iterations) and to add a fraction of it to the change.  The fraction added is called momentum and is supposed to speed you up through regions of the error surface where there is not much change and slow you down where there is detail.

```
weight_change = (outer_error*inner_output_value*learning_rate) + (last_change*momentum)
```

There are algorithms for adjusting the learning rate and momentum as the training proceeds.

The weight is then updated by adding the change

```
new_weight = old_weight + weight_change
```

I had a look through your code, but rather than correct it and post that I thought it was better to describe back prop for you so you can code it up yourself.  If you understand it you'll be able to tune it for your circumstances too.

HTH and good luck.

Comment: I try to fix my code with your suggestions, (I did not get the momentum in it yet) but I am still having problem with the backprop system.  (To me at least) It looks like you were telling me to do the same thing but just bundle move numbers into the error value.  
I feel as I am missing something small but important and that is causing my backprop to not function.

Comment: I've tried a couple of times to figure out what your code is doing, but have given up. I think the total_error value you calculate is probably wrong because you do it for a layer and call DSigmoid twice.  I suggest you do a single iteration with 2 rows of input data on paper or in Excel so you know how the whole thing works. Then get your network to spit out its weights so you can compare it to your calculations. By that stage you should understand a) what is supposed to happen and b) what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I tried to implement the algorithm you described... but its not quite learning. Mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973950/super-minimal-xor-neural-network-cannot-learn-what-did-i-do-wrong?noredirect=1#comment63395814_37973950

Comment: nice explanation :)

Answer (score 5):

How about this open-source code. It defines a simple 1 hidden layer net (2 input, 2 hidden, 1 output) and solves XOR problem:

https://web.archive.org/web/20131105002125/http://www.sylbarth.com/mlp.php

Answer (score 3):

What about a simple function approximation network like the one that predicts and fits a Sine Function. Also, I think, avoiding class during implementation is a must for getting the basics easily. Let's consider a single hidden layer network.

```
//Had a lot of trouble with shuffle

#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.141592653589793238463
#define N

#define epsilon 0.1
#define epoch 2000

using namespace std;
// Just for GNU Plot issues
extern "C" FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);

// Defining activation functions
//double sigmoid(double x) { return 1.0f / (1.0f + exp(-x)); }
//double dsigmoid(double x) { return x * (1.0f - x); }
double tanh(double x) { return (exp(x)-exp(-x))/(exp(x)+exp(-x)) ;}
double dtanh(double x) {return 1.0f - x*x ;}

double lin(double x) { return x;}
double dlin(double x) { return 1.0f;}

double init_weight() { return (2*rand()/RAND_MAX -1); }
double MAXX = -9999999999999999; //maximum value of input example

// Network Configuration
static const int numInputs = 1;
static const int numHiddenNodes = 7;
static const int numOutputs = 1;

// Learning Rate
const double lr = 0.05f;

double hiddenLayer[numHiddenNodes];
double outputLayer[numOutputs];

double hiddenLayerBias[numHiddenNodes];
double outputLayerBias[numOutputs];

double hiddenWeights[numInputs][numHiddenNodes];
double outputWeights[numHiddenNodes][numOutputs];

static const int numTrainingSets = 50;
double training_inputs[numTrainingSets][numInputs];
double training_outputs[numTrainingSets][numOutputs];

// Shuffling the data with each epoch
void shuffle(int *array, size_t n)
{
    if (n > 1) //If no. of training examples > 1
    {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);
            int t = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }
    }
}

// Forward Propagation. Only used after training is done.
void predict(double test_sample[])
{
    for (int j=0; j<numHiddenNodes; j++)
    {
        double activation=hiddenLayerBias[j];
        for (int k=0; k<numInputs; k++)
        {
            activation+=test_sample[k]*hiddenWeights[k][j];
        }
        hiddenLayer[j] = tanh(activation);
    }

    for (int j=0; j<numOutputs; j++)
    {
        double activation=outputLayerBias[j];
        for (int k=0; k<numHiddenNodes; k++)
        {
            activation+=hiddenLayer[k]*outputWeights[k][j];
        }
        outputLayer[j] = lin(activation);
    }
    //std::cout<<outputLayer[0]<<"\n";
    //return outputLayer[0];
    //std::cout << "Input:" << training_inputs[i][0] << " " << training_inputs[i][1] << "    Output:" << outputLayer[0] << "    Expected Output: " << training_outputs[i][0] << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ///TRAINING DATA GENERATION
    for (int i = 0; i < numTrainingSets; i++)
    {
        double p = (2*PI*(double)i/numTrainingSets);
        training_inputs[i][0] = (p);
        training_outputs[i][0] = sin(p);

        ///FINDING NORMALIZING FACTOR
        for(int m=0; m<numInputs; ++m)
            if(MAXX < training_inputs[i][m])
                MAXX = training_inputs[i][m];
        for(int m=0; m<numOutputs; ++m)
            if(MAXX < training_outputs[i][m])
                MAXX = training_outputs[i][m];

    }

    ///NORMALIZING
    for (int i = 0; i < numTrainingSets; i++)
    {
        for(int m=0; m<numInputs; ++m)
            training_inputs[i][m] /= 1.0f*MAXX;

        for(int m=0; m<numOutputs; ++m)
            training_outputs[i][m] /= 1.0f*MAXX;

        cout<<"In: "<<training_inputs[i][0]<<"  out: "<<training_outputs[i][0]<<endl;
    }
    ///WEIGHT & BIAS INITIALIZATION
    for (int i=0; i<numInputs; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<numHiddenNodes; j++) {
            hiddenWeights[i][j] = init_weight();
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<numHiddenNodes; i++) {
        hiddenLayerBias[i] = init_weight();
        for (int j=0; j<numOutputs; j++) {
            outputWeights[i][j] = init_weight();
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<numOutputs; i++) {
        //outputLayerBias[i] = init_weight();
        outputLayerBias[i] = 0;
    }

    ///FOR INDEX SHUFFLING
    int trainingSetOrder[numTrainingSets];
    for(int j=0; j<numInputs; ++j)
        trainingSetOrder[j] = j;


    ///TRAINING
    //std::cout<<"start train\n";
    vector<double> performance, epo; ///STORE MSE, EPOCH
    for (int n=0; n < epoch; n++)
    {
        double MSE = 0;
        shuffle(trainingSetOrder,numTrainingSets);
        std::cout<<"epoch :"<<n<<"\n";
        for (int i=0; i<numTrainingSets; i++)
        {
            //int i = trainingSetOrder[x];
            int x=i;
            //std::cout<<"Training Set :"<<x<<"\n";
            /// Forward pass
            for (int j=0; j<numHiddenNodes; j++)
            {
                double activation=hiddenLayerBias[j];
                //std::cout<<"Training Set :"<<x<<"\n";
                 for (int k=0; k<numInputs; k++) {
                    activation+=training_inputs[x][k]*hiddenWeights[k][j];
                }
                hiddenLayer[j] = tanh(activation);
            }

            for (int j=0; j<numOutputs; j++) {
                double activation=outputLayerBias[j];
                for (int k=0; k<numHiddenNodes; k++)
                {
                    activation+=hiddenLayer[k]*outputWeights[k][j];
                }
                outputLayer[j] = lin(activation);
            }

            //std::cout << "Input:" << training_inputs[x][0] << " " << "    Output:" << outputLayer[0] << "    Expected Output: " << training_outputs[x][0] << "\n";
            for(int k=0; k<numOutputs; ++k)
                MSE += (1.0f/numOutputs)*pow( training_outputs[x][k] - outputLayer[k], 2);

           /// Backprop
           ///   For V
            double deltaOutput[numOutputs];
            for (int j=0; j<numOutputs; j++) {
                double errorOutput = (training_outputs[i][j]-outputLayer[j]);
                deltaOutput[j] = errorOutput*dlin(outputLayer[j]);
            }

            ///   For W
            double deltaHidden[numHiddenNodes];
            for (int j=0; j<numHiddenNodes; j++) {
                double errorHidden = 0.0f;
                for(int k=0; k<numOutputs; k++) {
                    errorHidden+=deltaOutput[k]*outputWeights[j][k];
                }
                deltaHidden[j] = errorHidden*dtanh(hiddenLayer[j]);
            }

            ///Updation
            ///   For V and b
            for (int j=0; j<numOutputs; j++) {
                //b
                outputLayerBias[j] += deltaOutput[j]*lr;
                for (int k=0; k<numHiddenNodes; k++)
                {
                    outputWeights[k][j]+= hiddenLayer[k]*deltaOutput[j]*lr;
                }
            }

            ///   For W and c
            for (int j=0; j<numHiddenNodes; j++) {
                //c
                hiddenLayerBias[j] += deltaHidden[j]*lr;
                //W
                for(int k=0; k<numInputs; k++) {
                  hiddenWeights[k][j]+=training_inputs[i][k]*deltaHidden[j]*lr;
                }
            }
        }
        //Averaging the MSE
        MSE /= 1.0f*numTrainingSets;
        //cout<< "  MSE: "<< MSE<<endl;
        ///Steps to PLOT PERFORMANCE PER EPOCH
        performance.push_back(MSE*100);
        epo.push_back(n);
    }

    // Print weights
    std::cout << "Final Hidden Weights\n[ ";
    for (int j=0; j<numHiddenNodes; j++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int k=0; k<numInputs; k++) {
            std::cout << hiddenWeights[k][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "] ";
    }
    std::cout << "]\n";

    std::cout << "Final Hidden Biases\n[ ";
    for (int j=0; j<numHiddenNodes; j++) {
        std::cout << hiddenLayerBias[j] << " ";

    }
    std::cout << "]\n";
    std::cout << "Final Output Weights";
    for (int j=0; j<numOutputs; j++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for (int k=0; k<numHiddenNodes; k++) {
            std::cout << outputWeights[k][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Final Output Biases\n[ ";
    for (int j=0; j<numOutputs; j++) {
        std::cout << outputLayerBias[j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "]\n";


    /* This part is just for plotting the results.
       This requires installing GNU Plot. You can also comment it out.
    */
    //Plot the results
    vector<float> x;
    vector<float> y1, y2;
    //double test_input[1000][numInputs];
    int numTestSets = numTrainingSets;
    for (float i = 0; i < numTestSets; i=i+0.25)
    {
        double p = (2*PI*(double)i/numTestSets);
        x.push_back(p);
        y1.push_back(sin(p));
        double test_input[1];
        test_input[0] = p/MAXX;
        predict(test_input);
        y2.push_back(outputLayer[0]*MAXX);
    }

    FILE * gp = popen("gnuplot", "w");
    fprintf(gp, "set terminal wxt size 600,400 \n");
    fprintf(gp, "set grid \n");
    fprintf(gp, "set title '%s' \n", "f(x) = x sin (x)");
    fprintf(gp, "set style line 1 lt 3 pt 7 ps 0.1 lc rgb 'green' lw 1 \n");
    fprintf(gp, "set style line 2 lt 3 pt 7 ps 0.1 lc rgb 'red' lw 1 \n");
    fprintf(gp, "plot '-' w p ls 1, '-' w p ls 2 \n");

    ///Exact f(x) = sin(x) -> Green Graph
    for (int k = 0; k < x.size(); k++) {
        fprintf(gp, "%f %f \n", x[k], y1[k]);
    }
    fprintf(gp, "e\n");

    ///Neural Network Approximate f(x) = xsin(x) -> Red Graph
    for (int k = 0; k < x.size(); k++) {
        fprintf(gp, "%f %f \n", x[k], y2[k]);
    }
    fprintf(gp, "e\n");

    fflush(gp);
    ///FILE POINTER FOR SECOND PLOT (PERFORMANCE GRAPH)
    FILE * gp1 = popen("gnuplot", "w");
    fprintf(gp1, "set terminal wxt size 600,400 \n");
    fprintf(gp1, "set grid \n");
    fprintf(gp1, "set title '%s' \n", "Performance");
    fprintf(gp1, "set style line 1 lt 3 pt 7 ps 0.1 lc rgb 'green' lw 1 \n");
    fprintf(gp1, "set style line 2 lt 3 pt 7 ps 0.1 lc rgb 'red' lw 1 \n");
    fprintf(gp1, "plot '-' w p ls 1 \n");

    for (int k = 0; k < epo.size(); k++) {
        fprintf(gp1, "%f %f \n", epo[k], performance[k]);
    }
    fprintf(gp1, "e\n");

    fflush(gp1);

    system("pause");
    //_pclose(gp);

    return 0;
}
```

I too have been trying to learn simple (shallow) Neural Networks while avoiding any high level tools. I have tried to maintain some of my learning at this [repository](https://github.com/PrashantDandriyal/Neural-Networks-In-Cpp).